# Node.js http.request keepAlive

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to use `http.Agent({ keepAlive: true})` on `http.request` to keep the connection open for future requests.

I created a simple server to log each new connection but when i run my *request.js* the server logs two new connections.

How can i use the HTTP keep-alive with Node.js native modules?

request.js:

```
const http = require("http");

const agent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});

var req1 = http.request({
    agent: agent,
    method: "GET",
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 3000
}, function (res1) {
    console.log("REQUEST_1");

    var req2 = http.request({
        agent: agent,
        method: "GET",
        hostname: "localhost",
        port: 3000
    }, function (res2) {
        console.log("REQUEST_2");
    });

    req2.end();
});

req1.end();
```

server.js:

```
const http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.end('OK');
    console.log("REQUEST");
})

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("NEW CONNECTION");
})

server.listen(3000);
```

output:

```
NEW CONNECTION
REQUEST
NEW CONNECTION
REQUEST
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `maxSockets` options like this:

```
const agent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
    maxSockets: 1
});
```

By default `maxSockets` is set to `Infinity` - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options

Full example on node v10

```
const http = require("http");

const agent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
    maxSockets: 1
});

var req1 = http.request({
    agent: agent,
    method: "GET",
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 3000
}, function (res1) {
    console.log("REQUEST_1");

    res1.on('data', function () {
        console.log("REQUEST_1 data");
    });

    res1.on('end', function () {
        console.log("REQUEST_1 end");
    });

    var req2 = http.request({
        agent: agent,
        method: "GET",
        hostname: "localhost",
        port: 3000
    }, function (res2) {
        console.log("REQUEST_2");

        res2.on('data', function () {
            console.log("REQUEST_2 data");
        });

        res2.on('end', function () {
            console.log("REQUEST_2 end");
        });
    });
    req2.end();
});
req1.end();
```

Comment: I got the same result, however now the "REQUEST_2" was delayed. It seems like the second request is waiting for the first one to close.

Comment: Thanks. Now its working, i was not handling the events ''data' and 'end' of the requests.

Comment: Why it doesn't work without handling (even a 'noop' is fine) the events 'data' and 'end' of the requests?

Comment: The explenation is here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest , starts with "If no 'response' handler is added". You can omit `end` event in this case but I've added this to cover it all.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Node.js v19, the `keepAlive` option is set to true by default for all outgoing HTTP(s) connections.

You can read more about it on [Node.js's v19 documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v19-release-announce/#http-s-1-1-keepalive-by-default).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't make clear that the code posted will allow only *one* request simultaneously per host per thread.

That is usually not what you want and will lead to requests slowing down waiting for the previous one to complete.

Comment: This is a helpful clarification, but it should really be a comment on the other answer, not an answer of its own. By itself, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

your demo not set res1's on `data` listener ,it will cause the socket not be close ,so the second request have to create a new connect to server ,just add a `data` listener